# Swallowing Exception and continue controller from event listener in symfony2

Tags: symfony, exception, event-listener

I'm listening to `kernel.exception` from an event listener in Symfony2.
I need to swallow the exception and just add a `FlashBag` message and let controller continue as normal.
Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

That's just how exception **do not work**. Once you end up in that handler, you cannot go back to your controller. However, you could wrap individual calls that produce those `Exception`s:

```
# Controller's code prior to error
try {
    # Code that could trigger exception
}catch(\Exception $e){
    # Add message to FlashBag
}
# Controller's code after the error
```

But you have to take into consideration the validity of moving forward. If an `Exception` has been thrown that means that some operation could not complete successfully. You will end up with some data missing (or invalid) and produce some **logical errors** down the way.

In case you decide to do it you should always assign some default values prior to `try-catch` or within `catch` block.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, In this situation no data is lost, I'm catching Doctrine's `foreign key constraint fail` and showing an error instead of 500 error page but I want to do it globally and not by wrapping each of delete parts of application's code. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, I see the motivation for that... I wish I had better answer for you. Maybe someone would have an idea...

Comment: A general Idea is to redirect the user to the same page (controller) in the exception listener, and write your controllers in such a way that this doesn't disrupt the logic.e.g: take action based on request method ('GET', 'POST').

Comment: @4r1y4n: Maybe the good way to go would be to disable `FOREIGN KEY` constraints before request and enable them afterwards? Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: @JovanPerovic: I'm using mysql; but I don't want to prevent the exception; i need to keep the relations and prevent user to delete anything that has dependents & just show an error message to user